# How to create a comment system in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, comments, system

How can i create a comment system in php which will not display the writers name.
Like- If a person comments then his/her name should not be displayed.

Comment: I am sorry Rishabh, but isn't your question a little broad? There are several different ways of hiding any text through CSS and Javascript, and you can also avoid placing that text in your HTML through PHP if you set the right conditions. You don't need to create a comment system in order to do so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the article that shows you how to make comment system using html css and php.

[Link: How to make comment system.](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/09/building-real-time-commenting-system/)